# Scrapy from Script. Will not export data

Tags: python-2.7, web, web-scraping, scrapy, twisted.internet

I am trying to run scrapy from a script and I cannot get the program to create the export file

I have tried to get the file to export in two different ways:

1. With a pipeline
2. With Feed export.

Both of these ways work when I run scrapy from the command line, but neither work when I run scrapy from a script.

I am not alone with this problem.  Here are two other similar unanswered questions.  I did not notice these until after I posted the question.

1. [JSON not working in scrapy when calling spider through a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080575/json-not-working-in-scrapy-when-calling-spider-through-a-python-script)
2. [Calling scrapy from a python script not creating JSON output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483898/calling-scrapy-from-a-python-script-not-creating-json-output-file)

Here is my code to run scrapy from the script.  It includes the settings to print an output file with both the pipeline and the feed exporter.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
import logging

from external_links.spiders.test import MySpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings = get_project_settings()

#manually set settings here
settings.set('ITEM_PIPELINES',{'external_links.pipelines.FilterPipeline':100,'external_links.pipelines.CsvWriterPipeline':200},priority='cmdline')
settings.set('DEPTH_LIMIT',1,priority='cmdline')
settings.set('LOG_FILE','Log.log',priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_URI','output.csv',priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', 'csv',priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_EXPORTERS',{'csv':'external_links.exporter.CsvOptionRespectingItemExporter'},priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_STORE_EMPTY',True,priority='cmdline')

def stop_reactor():
    reactor.stop()

dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
spider = MySpider()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start(loglevel=logging.DEBUG)
log.msg('reactor running...')
reactor.run()
log.msg('Reactor stopped...')
```

**In after I run this code the log says: "Stored csv feed (341 items) in: output.csv", but there is no output.csv to be found.**

here is my feed exporter code:

```
settings = get_project_settings()

#manually set settings here
settings.set('ITEM_PIPELINES',   {'external_links.pipelines.FilterPipeline':100,'external_links.pipelines.CsvWriterPipeline': 200},priority='cmdline')
settings.set('DEPTH_LIMIT',1,priority='cmdline')
settings.set('LOG_FILE','Log.log',priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_URI','output.csv',priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', 'csv',priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_EXPORTERS',{'csv':'external_links.exporter.CsvOptionRespectingItemExporter'},priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_STORE_EMPTY',True,priority='cmdline')


from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter


class CsvOptionRespectingItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        delimiter = settings.get('CSV_DELIMITER', ',')
        kwargs['delimiter'] = delimiter
        super(CsvOptionRespectingItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my pipeline code:

```
import csv

class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('items2.csv', 'wb'))

def process_item(self, item, spider): #item needs to be second in this list otherwise get spider object
    self.csvwriter.writerow([item['all_links'], item['current_url'], item['start_url']])

    return item
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Here is what working for me:

1. Put export uri into `settings.py`

   `FEED_URI='file:///tmp/feeds/filename.jsonlines'`
2. Create a `scrape.py` script next to your `scrapy.cfg` with the following content

   ```
    
   from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
   from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


   process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

   process.crawl('yourspidername') #'yourspidername' is the name of one of the spiders of the project.
   process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
   ```
3. Run : `python scrape.py`

Result: file is created.

**Note**: I don't have pipelines in my project. So not sure if the pipeline will filter or not your results.

**Also** : Here are the common pitfalls section on the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-from-script) which helped me