# Run Scrapy spider via script & configure the settings for output file

Tags: python, json

I have written a spider in scrapy & running it in a python script (not scrapy cmd prompt).
I want to configure settings, so as to get the Scrapped data in a particular file (say output.json).

I can get the result if I run following command on the prompt:"scrapy crawl myspider -o scrapedData.json -t json"

But I want the same output by running a script not via cmdline tool.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

```
settings = get_project_settings()
settings.overrides['FEED_URI'] = 'dealsOutput.json'
settings.overrides['FEED_FORMAT'] = 'json'

spider = dealsSpider()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
```

I found by looking at this code: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/commands/crawl.py#L34